# Using Babel to Get ApolloClient to ES5 CommonJS Module Format for Node Environment

Tags: node.js, babeljs, commonjs, graphql-js, apollo-server

## Using Babel to Get ApolloClient to ES5 CommonJS Module Format

Im trying to use Babel to get the apollo-client module to work as ES5 in a non-browser, node environment. I've gone through step below which always give me the same result.  Im trying to figure out if that result is right result for a node environment. When I import the babel processed documents into my project and call a method that should be exported, im getting, cannot find module. For context, the project is a fusetools.com demo. Fusetools does not support ES2015 Promises so the idea is that with the babel es2015 preset, it should work. I'm mostly chasing this down to learn something but it would be great if I could get it to work. Any comments on an easier way to do this, now that I understand it better, would be greatly appreciated. The project where I babeled the code can be found [here](https://github.com/aarmand/apollo-client-babel-commonjs-project). The fusetools project where i used the transformed code is [here](https://github.com/aarmand/InfiniteScrollerApollo).

The error I get is :

```
LOG: Error: JavaScript error in MainView.ux line 9: Name: Fuse.Scripting.Error
Error message: require(): module not found: js/apollo-client/ApolloClient.js
File name: MainView.ux
Line number: 9
Source line:        var ApolloClient = require('js/apollo-client/ApolloClient.js');
```

This is the code im trying to reach:

````
```
"use strict";

var networkInterface_1 = require('./transport/networkInterface');
var isUndefined = require('lodash.isundefined');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');
var isString = require('lodash.isstring');
var store_1 = require('./store');
var QueryManager_1 = require('./core/QueryManager');
var storeUtils_1 = require('./data/storeUtils');
var fragments_1 = require('./fragments');
var getFromAST_1 = require('./queries/getFromAST');
var DEFAULT_REDUX_ROOT_KEY = 'apollo';
function defaultReduxRootSelector(state) {
    return state[DEFAULT_REDUX_ROOT_KEY];
}
var ApolloClient = function () {
    function ApolloClient(_a) {
        var _this = this;
        var _b = _a === void 0 ? {} : _a,
            networkInterface = _b.networkInterface,
            reduxRootKey = _b.reduxRootKey,
            reduxRootSelector = _b.reduxRootSelector,
            initialState = _b.initialState,
            dataIdFromObject = _b.dataIdFromObject,
            resultTransformer = _b.resultTransformer,
            resultComparator = _b.resultComparator,
            _c = _b.ssrMode,
            ssrMode = _c === void 0 ? false : _c,
            _d = _b.ssrForceFetchDelay,
            ssrForceFetchDelay = _d === void 0 ? 0 : _d,
            _e = _b.mutationBehaviorReducers,
            mutationBehaviorReducers = _e === void 0 ? {} : _e,
            _f = _b.addTypename,
            addTypename = _f === void 0 ? true : _f,
            queryTransformer = _b.queryTransformer;
        this.middleware = function () {
            return function (store) {
                _this.setStore(store);
                return function (next) {
                    return function (action) {
                        var returnValue = next(action);
                        _this.queryManager.broadcastNewStore(store.getState());
                        return returnValue;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        if (reduxRootKey && reduxRootSelector) {
            throw new Error('Both "reduxRootKey" and "reduxRootSelector" are configured, but only one of two is allowed.');
        }
        if (reduxRootKey) {
            console.warn('"reduxRootKey" option is deprecated and might be removed in the upcoming versions, ' + 'please use the "reduxRootSelector" instead.');
            this.reduxRootKey = reduxRootKey;
        }
        if (queryTransformer) {
            throw new Error('queryTransformer option no longer supported in Apollo Client 0.5. ' + 'Instead, there is a new "addTypename" option, which is on by default.');
        }
        if (!reduxRootSelector && reduxRootKey) {
            this.reduxRootSelector = function (state) {
                return state[reduxRootKey];
            };
        } else if (isString(reduxRootSelector)) {
            this.reduxRootKey = reduxRootSelector;
            this.reduxRootSelector = function (state) {
                return state[reduxRootSelector];
            };
        } else if (typeof reduxRootSelector === 'function') {
            this.reduxRootSelector = reduxRootSelector;
        } else {
            this.reduxRootSelector = null;
        }
        this.initialState = initialState ? initialState : {};
        this.networkInterface = networkInterface ? networkInterface : networkInterface_1.createNetworkInterface({ uri: '/graphql' });
        this.addTypename = addTypename;
        this.resultTransformer = resultTransformer;
        this.resultComparator = resultComparator;
        this.shouldForceFetch = !(ssrMode || ssrForceFetchDelay > 0);
        this.dataId = dataIdFromObject;
        this.fieldWithArgs = storeUtils_1.storeKeyNameFromFieldNameAndArgs;
        if (ssrForceFetchDelay) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                return _this.shouldForceFetch = true;
            }, ssrForceFetchDelay);
        }
        this.reducerConfig = {
            dataIdFromObject: dataIdFromObject,
            mutationBehaviorReducers: mutationBehaviorReducers
        };
        this.watchQuery = this.watchQuery.bind(this);
        this.query = this.query.bind(this);
        this.mutate = this.mutate.bind(this);
        this.setStore = this.setStore.bind(this);
        this.resetStore = this.resetStore.bind(this);
    }
    ApolloClient.prototype.watchQuery = function (options) {
        this.initStore();
        if (!this.shouldForceFetch && options.forceFetch) {
            options = assign({}, options, {
                forceFetch: false
            });
        }
        fragments_1.createFragment(options.query);
        var fullDocument = getFromAST_1.addFragmentsToDocument(options.query, options.fragments);
        var realOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
            query: fullDocument
        });
        delete realOptions.fragments;
        return this.queryManager.watchQuery(realOptions);
    };
    ;
    ApolloClient.prototype.query = function (options) {
        this.initStore();
        if (!this.shouldForceFetch && options.forceFetch) {
            options = assign({}, options, {
                forceFetch: false
            });
        }
        fragments_1.createFragment(options.query);
        var fullDocument = getFromAST_1.addFragmentsToDocument(options.query, options.fragments);
        var realOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
            query: fullDocument
        });
        delete realOptions.fragments;
        return this.queryManager.query(realOptions);
    };
    ;
    ApolloClient.prototype.mutate = function (options) {
        this.initStore();
        var fullDocument = getFromAST_1.addFragmentsToDocument(options.mutation, options.fragments);
        var realOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
            mutation: fullDocument
        });
        delete realOptions.fragments;
        return this.queryManager.mutate(realOptions);
    };
    ;
    ApolloClient.prototype.subscribe = function (options) {
        this.initStore();
        var fullDocument = getFromAST_1.addFragmentsToDocument(options.query, options.fragments);
        var realOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {
            document: fullDocument
        });
        delete realOptions.fragments;
        delete realOptions.query;
        return this.queryManager.startGraphQLSubscription(realOptions);
    };
    ApolloClient.prototype.reducer = function () {
        return store_1.createApolloReducer(this.reducerConfig);
    };
    ApolloClient.prototype.initStore = function () {
        if (this.store) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.reduxRootSelector) {
            throw new Error('Cannot initialize the store because "reduxRootSelector" or "reduxRootKey" is provided. ' + 'They should only be used when the store is created outside of the client. ' + 'This may lead to unexpected results when querying the store internally. ' + "Please remove that option from ApolloClient constructor.");
        }
        this.setStore(store_1.createApolloStore({
            reduxRootKey: DEFAULT_REDUX_ROOT_KEY,
            initialState: this.initialState,
            config: this.reducerConfig
        }));
        this.reduxRootKey = DEFAULT_REDUX_ROOT_KEY;
    };
    ;
    ApolloClient.prototype.resetStore = function () {
        this.queryManager.resetStore();
    };
    ;
    ApolloClient.prototype.setStore = function (store) {
        var reduxRootSelector;
        if (this.reduxRootSelector) {
            reduxRootSelector = this.reduxRootSelector;
        } else {
            reduxRootSelector = defaultReduxRootSelector;
            this.reduxRootKey = DEFAULT_REDUX_ROOT_KEY;
        }
        if (isUndefined(reduxRootSelector(store.getState()))) {
            throw new Error('Existing store does not use apolloReducer. Please make sure the store ' + 'is properly configured and "reduxRootSelector" is correctly specified.');
        }
        this.store = store;
        this.queryManager = new QueryManager_1.QueryManager({
            networkInterface: this.networkInterface,
            reduxRootSelector: reduxRootSelector,
            store: store,
            addTypename: this.addTypename,
            resultTransformer: this.resultTransformer,
            resultComparator: this.resultComparator,
            reducerConfig: this.reducerConfig
        });
    };
    ;
    return ApolloClient;
}();
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.default = ApolloClient;
//# sourceMappingURL=ApolloClient.js.map
```
````

Any and all comments I might learn from are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use webpack like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // watch: true,
  entry: {
    ApolloClient: './config/ApolloClient.js',
    createNetworkInterface: './config/createNetworkInterface.js',
    Redux: './config/Redux.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build/Libs'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: '[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        use: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
  ],
};
```

Then in `config` directory you could have:

```
/* ApolloClient.js */
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

export default ApolloClient;
```

and

```
/* createNetworkInterface.js */
import { createNetworkInterface } from 'apollo-client/transport/networkInterface';

export default createNetworkInterface;
```

plus if you want to have Redux as well:

```
/* Redux.js */
import * as Redux from 'redux';

export default Redux;
```

However I was not able to get `gql` done this way and had to use bolav's fusepm.
Which you would use exactly as bolav has mention, first install it globally:
`npm install -G fusepm` and then `fusepm npm graphql-tag`

Once you have all these in place you can require them as follow:

```
var Redux = require('build/Libs/Redux');
var ApolloClient = require('build/Libs/ApolloClient');
var createNetworkInterface = require('build/Libs/createNetworkInterface');
var gql = require('fusejs_lib/graphql-tag_graphql-tag.umd');
```

This way still could use some TLC but for now, it works and get's the job done:

```
var networkInterface = createNetworkInterface.createNetworkInterface({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql',
});

var client = new ApolloClient.ApolloClient({
  networkInterface,
});

client.query({
  query: gql`
    query {
      allPosts {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            headline
            summary(length: 80)
            body
            createdAt
            updatedAt
            personByAuthorId {
              firstName
              lastName
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
})
.then(data => data.data.allPosts.edges.forEach(node => pages.add(createPage(node))))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Also if you like I've setup a whole project along with server that might be of an interest to you: [fuseR](https://github.com/Bartekus/fuseR)

Answer (score 3):

I made [fusepm](https://github.com/bolav/fusepm), which has a mode to convert npm modules to run them under FuseTools. It's still has a lot of bugs, but at least I managed to come longer than you:

```
fuse create app apolloc
cd apolloc
npm install apollo-client
fusepm npm apollo-client
```

And then in your javascript:

```
<JavaScript>
    var ApolloClient = require('fusejs_lib/apollo-client.js');
</JavaScript>
```

fusepm uses Babel, with some custom plugins.